# Output only lowest and the highest in a range of prices

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a number of custom post type shop items saved on my Wordpress site with various prices attached as custom meta in the string form `$nn.nn` or simply `$n`.

I would like to output the following:

> Prices range from £nn.nn to £nn.nn?

So, I'd like to query the price meta and only show the lowest and highest.

Is it possible to do this in PHP?

This is all I've managed to come up with so far, but it simply outputs a list of all prices separated by a comma:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'shop-items',);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    echo 'Prices range from ';

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $price  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'itemprice', true );

        echo '$price . ', ';

    endwhile;

endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort()` for the array of prices

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
$pricearray=array();
echo 'Prices range from ';

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $price  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'itemprice', true );
$price=str_replace("£","",$price);
if(!empty($price)){
     $pricearray[]= $price;
 }else{
 $pricearray[]= "0";
 }
endwhile;

endif;

sort($pricearray, SORT_NUMERIC);
$minprice=$pricearray[0];
$maxprice=$pricearray[count($pricearray)-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried echoing $minprice and $maxprice but see nothing (both empty). Any ideas?

Comment: `print_r($pricearray)` and  see what you get in the array or still empty array

Comment: I'm getting a 1 when I print_r

Comment: and when you `echo $price` in while loop how many value you see

Comment: I see all of them with a 1 at the end

Comment: i have edited my answer and removes the `$pricearray=rsort($pricearray);` assigning of sorted array now try the above and let me konw what you got

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28100/discussion-between-dianuj-and-user1444027)

Answer (score 1):

First declare the variables (which will contain the result):

```
$min_price = INF;
$max_price = -INF;
```

In your loop do:

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'itemprice', true );
if ($price < $min_price)
    $min_price = $price;
if ($price > $max_price)
    $max_price = $price;
```

At the end write (before the if):

```
echo "$min_price to $max_price";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to show the highest price but not the lowest for some reason. Any ideas? I tried changing if ($price <= $min_price) but that didn't make any difference

Comment: write `error_reporting(0);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the beginning and tell me if there's any difference...? (any error)

Comment: Should I not put 'echo' before error_reporting ? When I remove echo it shows nothing